# Check if paginate

Tags: pagination, limit

Below is my paginate code.
How can I check if there is more than one page? At the moment when there is only one I'm getting a '1' appear at the bottom (the page number) which looks odd. Ideally I only want it to show the pagination if the number of entries exceeds the limit, so only if it needs to display a link to the next page.

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('insights').limit(1) as entriesOnPage %}
    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
    <article>
        {% for image in entry.blogImage %}
        <img src="{{ image.getUrl()}}" alt="{{ image.title }}" class="gutter-bottom--half"/>
        {% endfor %}
        <h3><a class="descrete-link" href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h3>
        {{ entry.body|hacksaw(chars='300', append='...') }}
        <br>
        <br>            
        <p><a class="button button--blue gutter-bottom--half" href="{{ entry.url }}">Continue reading</a></p>
        <div class="col-12-nf gutter-bottom">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </article>
    <br>
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous</a>{% endif %}

{% for page, url in paginate.getPrevUrls(5) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

<span class="current">{{ paginate.currentPage }}</span>


{% for page, url in paginate.getNextUrls(5) %}
    <a href="{{ url }}">{{ page }}</a>
{% endfor %}

{% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next</a>{% endif %}


{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `paginate.totalPages` variable will give you the total number of pages that are generated by the `paginate` tag. So you can wrap your display of pages around a conditional that checks to see if this is greater than 1.

```
{% if paginate.totalPages > 1 %}

    {# output current pages and pagination navigation here #}

{% endif %}
```

More details, including a full list of variables available, can be found in the [pagination docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate).

Answer (score 2):

The above doesn't display any paging even when there is paging. It needs to be pageInfo not paginate:

```
{% if pageInfo.totalPages > 1 %}

    {# output current pages and pagination navigation here #}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Nicole: The [craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate) use ``pageInfo`` in the example but if you don't specify, [``paginate``](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/paginate#the-pageInfo-variable) is used by default.